# Merge a feature branch to a different trunk branch than it was created from?

Tags: tfs

I have a situation where we were working on feature branches against a main development branch ('trunk') and each release cycle, a release branch would be taken from the current development branch.

However, a release was cancelled very late on and instead we were asked to issue the previous release with only some features - *after* these were all integrated into the main dev branch.

So what happened was the previous release branch was taken as the base of the new mini-release, and we now have to re-apply specific changes that were already made against the development branch. I luckily still have my feature branch and it was never merged. It is based on the development branch, however my branch was taken fairly early on in the release cycle and was not updated by re-merging parent (trunk) changes - so my branch's parent is actually not too dissimilar from the new branch I need to apply it to.

I know TFS has some facilities for re-parenting and baseless merges but what is likely to work best? More importantly if I try re-parenting, can I break my branch or am I safe that I can try things, back them out and try again if there are problems?

My branch is fairly large, maybe 50 changesets applied to quite a few separate modules. I suppose I could try to apply each changeset one-by-one instead?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, baseless merges are always terrible.  In most cases I find diffing and merging the two branches manually via a compare tool (like BeyondCompare) is easier and more reliable than using the TFS tooling.

That being said I would challenge you to consider going to a single main branch.  We made the leap (a huge leap for us at the time) but it has paid dividends many times over at this point.  The key is being Release Ready:

https://dotnetcatch.com/2016/02/16/are-you-release-ready/